# Proving the interior of a set [Homework]

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to find the interior of the following set:

$E = [0,5] \cup (5,7)$, and prove it.
I found the union of the set to be $[0,7)$, and thus found the interior to be $(0,7)$.
I'm not sure how to prove this is true using the definition of a closed set i.e. there exists a delta such that for an $x$ element of $E$, $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ is contained in $E$?

Sorry about the lack of quantifiers, I haven't learned how to write them yet.
Any step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* For $x \in (0,7)$ let $\delta := \min\{7-x, x\} > 0$.